# Neural Network Error in R language, probably an error on the train data

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm Trying to run this code, as I already ran DecisionTree, Knn, SVM, RandomForests, I think it have to work but I receive the error

```
neuralnet(poisonous~.,
          data = treino,
          hidden = 2,
          linear.output = F,
          likelihood = T
          )
```

Here is the error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : 
  colunas indefinidas selecionadas
```

Here Is the data set

```
> str(treino)
'data.frame':   6499 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ poisonous               : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ cap-shape               : num  3 6 3 3 6 3 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ cap-surface             : num  4 3 4 4 4 3 4 3 4 1 ...
 $ cap-color               : num  4 9 5 5 3 5 3 3 5 4 ...
 $ bruises                 : num  2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ odor                    : num  6 4 6 6 3 6 6 3 6 6 ...
 $ gill-spacing            : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ gill-size               : num  1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ gill-color              : num  6 3 10 11 1 6 8 1 6 6 ...
 $ stalk-shape             : num  2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ stalk-root              : num  2 3 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 4 ...
 $ stalk-surface-above-ring: num  3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ stalk-surface-below-ring: num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ stalk-color-above-ring  : num  4 8 4 4 8 6 4 8 4 8 ...
 $ stalk-color-below-ring  : num  4 8 4 8 8 6 4 8 4 8 ...
 $ veil-color              : num  3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ ring-number             : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ring-type               : num  5 5 5 5 1 5 5 1 5 1 ...
 $ spore-print-color       : num  4 3 3 4 8 9 4 8 3 4 ...
 $ population              : num  5 3 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 4 ...
 $ habitat                 : num  1 4 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 ...
```

I've heard that it can be the names of columns so I'm going to print it here too, but I haven't noticed any problem

```
> colnames(treino)
 [1] "poisonous"                "cap-shape"                "cap-surface"             
 [4] "cap-color"                "bruises"                  "odor"                    
 [7] "gill-spacing"             "gill-size"                "gill-color"              
[10] "stalk-shape"              "stalk-root"               "stalk-surface-above-ring"
[13] "stalk-surface-below-ring" "stalk-color-above-ring"   "stalk-color-below-ring"  
[16] "veil-color"               "ring-number"              "ring-type"               
[19] "spore-print-color"        "population"               "habitat"
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) :
> colunas indefinidas selecionadas

Comment: I've found the error, it really was the names, ' - ' most exactly, the make.names() function worked, may I deleter the question?

Comment: You could delete it but you could also search for a duplicate and if none is found then edit the title to something like "neuralnet errors when column names vcontain dashes `-`" and then write an answer  and later accept it. Then you get the cred for documenting an infelicity. Seems the code should have handled this better.

Comment: You could also try the cito package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cito/index.html) which is faster and has more state-of-the art features from deep learning